# Center footer in a container with dynamic width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use resizable split views with [split.js](https://split.js.org/)

I have a very basic setup with 2 panes

How can I center bottom-footer in the right pane?

Since the width of the pain is dynamic the footer doesn't centered properly once pane resized.

I've tried all possible positioning - absolute, fixed, sticky, relative but nothing seems to be work.

---

**JSFiddle**

```js
Split(['.split-left', '.split-right'], {
    gutterSize: 10,
    sizes: [33,67]     // in %
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;

    overflow: hidden;
}


.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.split {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border: 0px solid;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.split-left {

    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    padding: 20px;

    padding-top: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;

}


.split-right {

    background-color: rgb(253,253,253);
    background-color: white;

    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;

    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    
}

.gutter {
    cursor: col-resize !important;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
  

.footer { 
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 60%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/split.js/1.5.11/split.min.js"></script>

 <body>
 
 
  <div class="content">
  
  <div class="split split-left">
  </div>
  
   <div class="split split-right">
    <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
  
   </body>
```

Comment: can you provide a working demo ?

Comment: @KareemDabbeet updated question with jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `css flexbox`

```
.split-right { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; // center horizontally
    align-items: center; // center vertically
}
```

[css flexbox tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is lots of content in `split-right` pane above footer. I can't affect its positioning. I need to center footer only. Check out the updated question with jsfiddle.

Comment: Actually, it helped. Thanks a lot! Marked as accepted.